# Tip Calculator App Issues

Tags: android

I've been working on the 'Tip Calculator' app for Android and I have a couple of questions.

I'm supposed to (in the process of creating the GUI) use some `EditText`s to allow the user to enter the bill amount and read the calculated total bill. In the version I have, there is no `EditText` anywhere in the Visual Layout Editor, only `CheckText`. Are these the same?

Whenever I try to edit the Java code for the app, as per the book I have, I keep getting the message:

> Thus and such is never used

For example, with

```
private static final String BILL_TOTAL = "BILL_TOTAL';
```

or anything from the import Android list, other than the one referring to a bundle. I'm Not sure how to resolve this. I have some experience with C and C++, but Java is new to me.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the issue you are having?

Answer (score 1):

The warning that tells you that a variable or method or import is not used can be ignored, especially if you just haven't gotten to using it yet. It's a warning and not an error, so your app should compile regardless.

I don't know what you're using to build your layout (eclipse? I use Intellij Idea), but to add an EditText, you can edit the layout file by hand. Add a line similar to:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/myEditText android:width="FILL_PARENT" android:height="WRAP_CONTENT"/>
```

As a general rule, I like to edit these things by hand. Then, when something breaks or doesn't work as I expect it to, I have some grasp of what's in there, and so I can usually fix it. The value gained by learning how to create a layout by hand easily offsets the value of the time that you'll save.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks...that clears things up. The book I'm going by has me using the Visual Layout Editor, though I'm probably gonna try doing things by hand, if all else fails. And yes, I am using the Eclipse (3.7 - Indigo). Thanks again...

Comment: If this was helpful (though... it didn't actually answer your question of whether an EditText and a CheckText are the same thing... They are not, btw), feel free to mark it as the answer. :)